# partial template specialization

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I have a scenario in which there is a template class

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
class Foo
{
 typedef Y::NestedType Bar;

 int A (Bar thing);
 void B();
 int C(X that);

 // other stuff
};
```

and then I would like the A() method to have a different behavior when X is a given type (but B and C can stay the same, and the actual code actually has about 10 other methods, a few of which are quite lengthy and subject to frequent tweaking.. so I would rather avoid making a full-class specialization and copy&paste the full class implementation)

I went on and wrote:

```
template<typename T>
int Foo<MyType, T>::A(Bar thing);
```

but my compiler (clang 163.7.1) refused to even consider this as a template specialization of any sort.

Is there some syntax error hidden in the way I wrote the code, or is this coding style invalid C++? Unfortunately, even if other compilers do support the idiom, my company is stuck with clang.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: I don't know if this helps you, but remember that partial specialization of template functions is not allowed in C++ (only of template classes).

Comment: you have to specialize the class first.

Comment: do you need the type of X in rest of the class or its functions? If not you could use a template function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use overloading

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
class Foo
{
 // allows to wrap up the arguments
 template<typename, typename>
 struct Types { };

 typedef Y::NestedType Bar;

 int A (Bar thing) {
   return AImpl(thing, Types<X, Y>());
 }

 void B();
 int C(X that);

 // other stuff
private:
  template<typename X1, typename Y1>
  int AImpl(Bar thing, Types<X1, Y1>) {
    /* generic */
  }

  template<typename Y1>
  int AImpl(Bar thing, Types<SpecificType, Y1>) {
    /* special */
  }
};
```

You cannot partially specialize a member of a class template. What you wrote would be the definition of a member function `A` of a partial specialization of the class template itself.

Comment: I have solved this using a class hierarchy. My previous Foo class became class Foo_base<X,Y>. Then, I have class Foo<X,Y> : public Foo_base<X,Y> that only redefines the constructors and assignment operators. Then, my partially specialized thing is in a class template specialization Foo<MyType, T> : public Foo_base<MyType, T> which only redefines the A() method from its parent (eventually what it does is { thong = Something(thing); ParentClass::A(thong); }). That's quite a bit of typing, but gets the job done. Thanks!

Comment: and anyway, I would love to be able to "partially specialize a member of a class template" :-) I don't see the point in forbidding this.